# How to test action have dispatched in pre render page on next js

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, next.js

I am trying to the test that an action have dispatched inside `getServerSiderProps` function.

I am using next + react + Redux

The test fails claiming `timesActionDispatched` equal 0 instead of 1

How i can I fix the test?

I tested the page manually and everything works so the problem is 100% in the test + the test was successful when the action been dispatched on the client side.

Comment: `getStaticProps`/`getServerSiderProps` doesn't get called during the tests since it's not actually running in the Next.js environment. You need to explicitly call it yourself during the test.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know that, How can I properly add this function to the test?

Comment: You can import it with `import RecipeList, { getStaticProps } from '<path-to-page>'` then call it as `await getStaticProps(mockedContext)` whenever you need to during the test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to juliomalves for the solution

***The test***

```js
jest.mock('../../../redux/actions/recipe', () => ({ 
    loadRecipeListAction: jest.fn() 
}));

test('should dispatch loadRecipeListAction', async () => {
    const listOfRecipes = (await getStaticProps()).props.listOfRecipes;
    render(
        <Provider store={store}>. 
            <RecipeList listOfRecipes={listOfRecipes} />
        </Provider>
    );
    const timesActionDispatched = loadRecipeListAction.mock.calls.length;

    expect(timesActionDispatched).toBe(1);
});
```

***The page***

```js
import DisplayRecipes from '../../components/recipes/DisplayRecipes';
import React from 'react';
import { loadRecipeListAction } from '../../redux/actions/recipe';
import { store } from '../../redux/store';

const RecipeList = ({ listOfRecipes }) => {
    return (
        <main data-testid='recipeList'>
            {listOfRecipes ? <DisplayRecipes recipesToDisplay={listOfRecipes} /> : null}
        </main>
    );
};

export async function getStaticProps() {
    await store.dispatch(loadRecipeListAction());
    const { listOfRecipes } = await store.getState().recipeReducer;

    return { props: { listOfRecipes }, revalidate: 10 };
}

export default RecipeList;
```